# How to make stacked bar chart with count values on y axis>

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a stacked barchart with gene sequencing data, where for each gene there is a tRF.type and Amino.Acid value. An example data set looks like this:

```
tRF <- c('tRF-26-OB1690PQR3E', 'tRF-27-OB1690PQR3P', 'tRF-30-MIF91SS2P46I')
tRF.type <- c('5-tRF', 'i-tRF', '3-tRF')
Amino.Acid <- c('Ser', 'Lys', 'Ser')
tRF.data <- data.frame(tRF, tRF.type, Amino.Acid)
```

I would like the x-axis to represent the amino acid type, the y-axis the number of counts of each tRF type and the the fill of the bars to represent each tRF type.

My code is:

```
ggplot(chart_data, aes(x = Amino.Acid, y = tRF.type, fill = tRF.type)) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
    ggtitle("LAN5 - 4 days post CNTF treatment") +
    xlab("Amino Acid") +
    ylab("tRF type")
```

However, it generates this graph, where the y-axis is labelled with the categories of tRF type. How can I change my code so that the y-axis scale is numerical and represents the counts of each tRF type?

[Barchart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Il2fg.png)

Comment: Could you please post some sample data?

Comment: Hi, I've updated with sample data. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OP and Welcome to SO.  In future questions, please, be sure to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) - meaning provide code, an image (if possible), and at least a representative dataset that can demonstrate your question or problem clearly.

TL;DR - don't use `stat="identity"`, just use `geom_bar()` without providing a stat, since default is to use the counts.  This should work:

```
ggplot(chart_data, aes(x = Amino.Acid, fill = tRF.type)) + geom_bar()
```

The dataset provided doesn't adequately demonstrate your issue, so here's one that can work. The example data herein consists of 100 observations and two columns: one called `Capitals` for randomly-selected uppercase letters and one `Lowercase` for randomly-selected lowercase letters.

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(
  Capitals=sample(LETTERS, 100, replace=TRUE),
  Lowercase=sample(letters, 100, replace=TRUE)
)
```

If I plot similar to your code, you can see the result:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Capitals, y=Lowercase, fill=Lowercase)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image]

You can see, the bars are stacked, but the y axis is all smooshed down.  The reason is related to understanding the difference between `geom_bar()` and `geom_col()`.  Checking [the documentation for these functions](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_bar.html), you can see that the main difference is that `geom_col()` will plot bars with heights equal to the `y` aesthetic, whereas `geom_bar()` plots by default according to `stat="count"`.  In fact, using `geom_bar(stat="identity")` is really just a complicated way of saying `geom_col()`.

Since your `y` aesthetic is not numeric, `ggplot` still tries to treat the discrete levels numerically.  It doesn't really work out well, and it's the reason why your axis gets smooshed down like that.  What you want, is `geom_bar(stat="count")`.... which is the same as just using `geom_bar()` without providing a `stat=`.

The one problem is that `geom_bar()` only accepts an `x` *or* a `y` aesthetic.  This means you should only give it one of them.  This fixes the issue and now you get the proper chart:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Capitals, fill=Lowercase)) + geom_bar()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You want your y-axis to be a count, not tRF.type. This code should give you the correct plot: I've removed the `y = tRF.type` from `ggplot()`, and `stat = "identity` from `geom_bar()` (it is using the default value of `stat = "count` instead).

```
ggplot(tRF.data, aes(x = Amino.Acid, fill = tRF.type)) + 
     geom_bar() + 
     ggtitle("LAN5 - 4 days post CNTF treatment") +
     xlab("Amino Acid") +
     ylab("tRF type")
```